# Minimizing the content of Listview

Tags: android, database, listview, textview

I am connecting my application to a database server, and displaying the content of the database in Listview.

The content of the database is huge in amount (more than 500 char). Whenever I try to display it in ListView, it displays all 500 char. I want to display only a limited amount of text, not all of it.

Is it possible to minimize the inner content of textview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can limit a `TextView` to a single line: add the following properties to your TextView

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"
android:inputType="text"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

The whole thing is a bit buggy hence the added properties that should make no difference ([Google Code Issue 882](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882#c9)).

Comment: Hi joseph, i tried both the case but still it does'nt converted into single line.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a substring followed by three periods to the textview of the listview item. You will have to override the baseadapter.

EDIT:

Actually you dont have to override the baseadapter... just store both of the values, the full and shortened, as name value pairs and use the short one for display and the long for reference.